# How can i make a square root button on my python calculator (i am a beginner)

Tags: python, calculator

```
def btnSquareRoot(self):
   result = False
   current = math.sqrt(text_Input)
   text_Input.set(current)
```

This is the code i tried using but i can't because `text_Input` is a string var
I am a beginner that's why for me it's hard to do this but my idea was to convert it somehow but i don't know-how

Comment: Convert it to string text_Input.set(str(current))

Answer (score 0):

convert text_input to int or float and then you will be able to find the square root.

`math.sqrt(int(text_Input)) or math.sqrt(float(text_Input))`

Answer (score 0):

to convert a string to a float you can use the float function as per:

```py
def btnSquareRoot(self): 
        result = False 
        current = math.sqrt(float(text_Input)) 
        text_Input.set(current)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str(i)` to convert a floating point number into a string, and `float(x)` to convert an string to a floating point number. So your code should be `text_Input.set(str(current))` instead of `text_Input.set(current)`, and `math.sqrt(float(text_Input.get()))` instead of `math.sqrt(text_Input)`.

Comment: it tells me `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'StringVar'`

Comment: Oh sorry, it's `float(text_Input.get())` @Shazam

Answer (score -1):

```py
import math

def calculator():
    print("Simple Calculator")

    while True:
        try:
            expression = input("Enter an expression (or 'exit' to quit): ")

            if expression.lower() == 'exit':
                print("Exiting the calculator. Goodbye!")
                break

            result = evaluate_expression(expression)
            print("Result:", result)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)

def evaluate_expression(expression):
    if 'sqrt' in expression:
        # Extract the number from the expression
        number = float(expression.replace('sqrt(', '').replace(')', ''))
        result = math.sqrt(number)
        return result
    return eval(expression)
calculator()
```